# What is the pinout of the Arduino MKR motor carrier when using external power supply, not the Li-Po battery

Tags: pins

I see there is a blue terminal connector an the tags below the PCB Vin, 5V, 3,3V and GND, but I am unsure where should I supply voltage to power up the board.
Also, in the product page it says the power can range from 6.5 to 11v, so what is those 5V and 3.3V all about?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Vin` means "Voltage Input". That's where you provide your power. That is the input to the voltage regulator.

5V and 3.3V are what the board uses internally and are provided for you to also use should you want to. These are outputs from the voltage regulators.

It's exactly the same (though more efficient and higher current) as almost every other Arduino.